# How can I get unique key value to distinguish a variable between python multiprocessing.Process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

How can I get inter-process unique key for a variable over multiprocessing.Process?

I have tried `id(variable)`, or address in eclipse debug mode(for example `A: <__main__.A object at 0x1ca9990>`)

However, they seem not to distinguish a variable over processes.

It is to check if a variable is shared as I intend.

This is my test code

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.variable = {'num' : 0}

def Rx(a):
    time.sleep(1)
    while 1:
        time.sleep(2)
        print "RX(id):", id(a.variable)
        print "RX:", a.variable

def Tx(a):
    while 1:
        time.sleep(2)
        print "TX(id):", id(a.variable)
        a.variable['num'] += 1
        print "TX:", a.variable

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()

    rx = multiprocessing.Process(target=Rx, args=(a,))
    tx = multiprocessing.Process(target=Tx, args=(a,))

    rx.start()
    tx.start()
```

And this is the output

```
TX(id): 33912768
TX: {'num': 1}
RX(id): 33912768
RX: {'num': 0}
TX(id): 33912768
TX: {'num': 2}
RX(id): 33912768
RX: {'num': 0}
TX(id): 33912768
TX: {'num': 3}
RX(id): 33912768
RX: {'num': 0}
TX(id): 33912768
TX: {'num': 4}
```

Though they(processes) print same `id(a.variable)`, they are not sharing the variable.

Comment: You would probably need to set up your own system. `id` in particular is only guaranteed to be unique within a particular Python instance (each process spawned by `multiprocessing` has its own python instance) and within an object's lifetime (which may be hard to track across processes). In cpython in particular, it is actually based on the C pointer value - ie, the address of the object in the interpreters virtual memory space.

Answer (score 0):

id and memory address (which are related in CPython) are only meaningful within a single process.  You cannot use them the way you are trying.  If you need some identifying information you will have to create it yourself and put it into the object you are sharing.

That being said, you are not sharing any objects.  When you pass a normal object as an argument to `multiprocessing.Process`, it will just make a copy for each process and no changes will be shared.

The easiest way to send data between processes is to push it through queues, but if you really need to share a mutable object, there are special classes in `multiprocessing` that allow this: `Value` and `Array` for simple values, and `Manager` for more complex objects.

ie:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def f(d, l):
    d[1] = '1'
    d['2'] = 2
    d[0.25] = None
    l.reverse()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()

    d = manager.dict()
    l = manager.list(range(10))

    p = Process(target=f, args=(d, l))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print d
    print l
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes for more details and some simple examples on using them.